# How can i display date in a 1 by 1 array when i use datestr?

Tags: matlab

I use `datestr` to transfer `732154.873773148` into `26-Jul-2004 20:58:14`, but when i ouput it to a .csv file, it will be an `1*20` array..., but what i want is to store it in a `1*1` array, how should i do?

And does there exist easy method to transfer `26-Jul-2004 20:58:14` to `2004/07/26 20:58:14`?

Thanks:)

```
data = csvread('4.csv');
date = data(:, 1);
loc = data(:, 2);
record_num = size(loc, 1);

result = zeros(record_num, 2);
new_date = datestr(date);
csvwrite('4_res.txt', new_date);
```

what i want is
`2004/07/26 20:58:14`

but it will be
`2,0,0,4,/,0,7,/,2,6, ,2,0,:,5,8,:,1,4`

Comment: Could you add sample code for exporting to csv?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have the date in the format `2004/07/26 20:58:14` you can use:

```
new_date = datestr(date,'mm/dd/yy HH:MM:SS');
```

To write a csv file with only a 1x1 cell you can use `dlmwrite` with the empty string as delimiter :

```
dlmwrite('4_res.txt',new_date, 'delimiter','')
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that, for Matlab, a string IS a character array.  As you've discovered `csvwrite` writes your 'string' as an array of integers (the ASCII codes of the characters in the string).  I don't think there is a way to force `csvwrite` to behave differently.

I think you will have to use `fprintf`, like this

```
fprintf(fid,datestr('26-Jul-2004 20:58:14'))
```

to get the output you want.  Here, `fid` is, of course, a handle for a file which you have opened (using `fopen`) with write access enabled.  As to writing the date string in the format you want, try:

```
fprintf(fid,datestr('26-Jul-2004 20:58:14', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS'))
```