# Concatenating all characters from a date into a 1x1 array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I need to concatenate all characters from a date/time string into a single 1x1 array.

If I do

```
K>> datestr(now, 'mmm dd yyyy - HH:MM')

ans =

Jan 04 2014 - 11:58

K>> size(datestr(now, 'mmm dd yyyy - HH:MM'))

ans =

     1    19
```

I end up with a 1x19 array for my date. It needs to be 1x1 as it will be the first of many other comma separated values exported to a single CSV file.

```
values =[
        software_version; date_time;     % <===== date_time should be 1x1 to fit
        P_total; P_total_SD; P_total_CV; %        in single cell
        t1;
        con_int1; con_int2; ...
        ];
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

My question is only partially addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619567/how-can-i-display-date-in-a-1-by-1-array-when-i-use-datestr), so I believe this is not a duplicate.
They suggest `dlmwrite` but that will not work for my case in which there are many other values being output to a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string has 19 characters, so as a character array it is necessarily of size 1x19. How to write this to a CSV file depends on the method you use; if the respective function supports to output strings to the file, I would expect it to accept a cell array as input. In that case, your 1x19 character array would be contained in one cell of the cell array:

```
values ={
        software_version; date_time;
        P_total; P_total_SD; P_total_CV;
        t1;
        con_int1; con_int2; ...
        };
```

The difference from your code is to replace `[]` by `{}`.